# Resolving Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): callback is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function which makes an API call and return data from the API call. Then it has to go a new page for which the callback() function is called. When I run the code, I do navigate to the new page, but like after a few milliseconds, I get an error which is shown in a screenshot below. The code I am using is :

```
export function editPost(id, callback) {
  const request = axios.get(`${API}/posts/${id}`,{headers});
    return dispatch => {
      return request.then((data) => {
        callback();
        console.log(data);
        dispatch({
          type: EDIT_POST,
          payload: data
        })
      })
    }
}
```

The error message I get is shown below:

[image: unhandled_rejection]

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: How are you calling `editPost ` function ?

Comment: Where did you define `callback()` function?

Comment: @ricky I am calling it like this:  ` componentDidMount() {
      const { id } = this.props.match.params;
      this.props.editPost(id);
      console.log(id)
  }`

Comment: while calling `editPost` It expect 2nd parameter(callback function) as well.

Comment: @ricky, that was the issue. Didn't notice until you mentioned.Thank you so much.Can you add it in the answer, so that i can accept your answer. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While calling `editPost` It expect 2nd parameter(callback function) as well.

Glad It helped you!

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the callback has been passed before call it.

```
if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to just pass the states as props from parent to child directly using

```
<childComponent {state1}={state1} {setState1}={setState1}/>
```

that's it

In your case `callback` will be passed as

```
{callback}={callback}
```